# Field Filter and Value Pick List for a Python Toolbox ValueTable Parameter

Tags: arcpy, python-toolbox, value-table

In an ArcGIS Python Toolbox (pyt file), how do I specify a filter for a Value Table parameter? In my value table I have two columns.  The first is a a field name derived from a selected table view and the second is a argument that should pass through with the field name.  I would like to filter the list of available fields by data type, and then define a pick list of values for the second field.

I've searched high and low, but setting a filter for a value table is not obvious, or it may not be possible.  When I attempt to specify a filter list for the field datatype in  the usual way the toolbox fails to load with an error message of "line 118, in getParameterInfoAttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'list'".  Where line 118 is where I try to specify the filter as in the code below.

I can specify list of values to populate the table, but I really need this to be user selected.

```
field_map = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName='Output Field Map',
        name='out_field_map',
        datatype='GPValueTable',
        parameterType='Required',
        direction='Input')
field_map.columns = [['Field', 'Field Name'], ['GPString', 'NVEL Attribute']]
field_map.parameterDependencies = [trees_table.name]
#specifying a filter list fails
#field_map.filter.list = ['Short', 'Long', 'Float', 'Double']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filters on Value Tables won't be available until 10.2.1. They'll be accessible as `Parameter.filters`, which will be a list of `Filter` objects the same as `Parameter.value` exists right now for single input parameters.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately that was the answer I expected.  Any suggestions on an a workaround?

Comment: What I've done before is have a set of inputs above the value table (feature layer and field), once a layer is selected it populates the field input, and once a field is selected it clears out the two controls and adds a row to the value table. Hacky but worked okay for me.

Comment: That doesn't sound too bad.  Thanks.

Comment: It's been a while since this question was first asked, and in the meantime 10.2.2 has been released. Is it now possible to filter on Value Tables?

Comment: Long story short... yes it is!
[ArcGIS Help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z00000006000000)

Comment: At 10.2.2 it is not working (at least not like it does at 10.3).  At 10.3 it is working with syntax like:  param2.filters[0].type="ValueList"
param2.filters[0].list = ["X"] to set the first column and param2.filters[1].type="ValueList"
param2.filters[1].list=["x"] to set the second column.  Thomas, how did you get it to work at 10.2.2?